# Carrying by handoff on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mishnah-berurah

I see this is discussed in the beiur halachah in the mishna berura 266:7:18. Correct me if I’m misunderstanding, but it seems like from here that it is perfectly acceptable to carry objects in repeated intervals of less than four amos, provided that it is not done by one person but, rather, by multiple people transferring from one to the other (and also as long as the item is not muktzeh). There are two things I would like to know here:

1. Is this lechatchila or is it only allowed in a case where one is caught on the road with no other options?
2. Is there an issue of transferring from a public to private domain in this scenario? Or are you only allowed to carry this way until the edge of the public and private domain?

Edit: For the second question, the mishna berurah (17) states that it is an issue and one should toss the item into his home in an awkward manner. This is allowed only because there is a financial loss at stake.

Comment: I think #1 is allowed lechatchila. Transferring domains is not though. The first mishna of Shabbos describes how two people can coordinate to avoid the biblical prohibition, but it's still forbidden rabbinically.

Comment: No I think you’re actually allowed to go between domains using this method. Can’t quote you a source but my rabbi was just telling us recently how he and his students made an assembly line/chain on Yom to transfer food from the shul to someone’s house

Comment: @CuriousYid wouldn’t that be a direct case of transferring from a public to a private domain? Even if it is technically less than four Amos with each handoff I don’t see how that restriction is surpassed.

Comment: @Rardal So maybe in that case it was allowed because it was on Yom Tov so I know the carrying rules are much more lenient, and also it was food they were carrying which is needed for the actual holiday

Comment: @CuriousYid I thought there was no issue of carrying on Yom Tov at all though?

Comment: @Seeker It's only permitted when it's needed for Yom Tov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the edited question, it seems that both questions are already answered.

The Biur Halacha is quoting the Pri Migadim that seems to say this is a lchatchila option.

The MB says that to switch the reshus is done k’lachar yad and is mutar in a situation that has no other reasonable option.

I just want to add to that, that the Biur Halacha in [349:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.349.5?lang=bi) asks that going from a karmalis to another reshus should be permitted since it’s a drabbanan and is less stringent than carrying 4 amos (he leaves it as a tzarich iyun)

> והנה מדברי התוספות משמע דשבות של פחות פחות מד"א חמור משבות של הוצאה מכרמלית לר"ה דהוצאה מכרמלית לר"ה [וה"ה לרה"י] מוכח שם ברש"י ותוספות דמותר בין השמשות לענין עירוב ולענין פחות מד"א ס"ל להתוספות וסייעתם דאסור בבין השמשות ולפי זה במקום דמתירין פחות פחות מד"א אפילו בר"ה כגון מי שהחשיך לו בדרך ואין עמו נכרי וכו' כ"ש דיש לנו להתיר הוצאה מכרמלית לאיזה רשות וקשה דבסימן רס"ו כתב שם הט"ז [וכמה אחרונים וכמה שהעתקתי שם במ"ב] דאינו מותר רק בטלטול פחות מד"א אבל לא בהוצאה מרשות לרשות אפילו לכרמלית וצ"ע:

Comment: It interesting. You'd think that this would be more common if it's lechatchila... Perhaps this isn't so prevalent because you wouldn't be allowed to handoff the item from a private domain to a public one and this is really only applicable when someone has an item when they are already in a public domain (or they found an item in public). Do you know if the item has only a little value, if one would be able to transfer domains in an awkward manner?

Comment: Doing things in an awkward manner is usually reserved for tough situations like high value, public need etc.  As far as how common it is, I recall using this hundreds of times as a kid when the ball rolled out of the eiruv and we had to get it back. No rabbi sanctioned it though, just some kids paskened based on their limited knowledge……